# How to display UI to display data

Tags: qt

I want to archive the code tips in my program. Logical code has finished. Now I want to show my data in the style of the picture.

What control should I use ?

[image: mpqdh.png]

Comment: A QListView or QListWidget will indeed get you there.  But if you're interested in user interface, consider rephrasing your scenario (in *MUCH, MUCH* more detail... diagrams and usage cases) and ask on [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com).  You might not actually be well-served by a list widget or combo box at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#details). Or try [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#details).